# Android convert JSONArray to String Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I get data from Json and there's a Json array. I want to convert that Json array into String array, so I can send it into another activity and show it in `ListView`.

Here's My java code

```
    if (jsonStr != null) {
        try {

            foodsFilter = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for (int i = 0; i < foodsFilter.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = foodsFilter.getJSONObject(i);
                if(c.getString("category_name").equals("Food")) {
                String category_name = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY_NAME);
                String filter_type = c.getString(TAG_FILTER_TYPE);
                //String item_list = c.getString(TAG_ITEM_LIST);
                JSONArray itemList = new JSONArray(c.getString("item_list"));
                String item_list = itemList.toString();

                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> filter = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                filter.put(TAG_CATEGORY_NAME, category_name);
                filter.put(TAG_FILTER_TYPE, filter_type);
                filter.put(TAG_ITEM_LIST, item_list);

                // adding contact to contact list
                foodsFilterList.add(filter);

                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

I try that code to convert the `JSONarray`, but I realized that code is for convert the `JSONArray` into `String`.

Here's my `JSON` data

```
[{"category_name":"Food","filter_type":"Sort by","field_name":"","type":"VALUE","table_name":"","item_list":["Ascending","Descending"]}]
```

I want to convert the `item_list` Array into like this

```
item_list = {"Ascending", "Descending"}
```

So I can send it into another activity use Intent and show it in `ListView`

Comment: Why not simply do this on the listview activity itself? Passing stuff using Intent is an expensive operation

Comment: Because I already have a listview on that activity. And I want to show that Data in another activity :D

Comment: @Matthew you can still parse the json in the listview activity itself.

Comment: @Raghunandan Do you mean, show the data on the same activity?

Comment: @Matthew you could show in the same activity or parse the data in Activity that has listview. passing through intent is expensive operation. If you can avoid it good

Comment: @Raghunandan Sorry if I ask too much. 

So, I have 2 activity. First is Filter activity that contain the data of `filter_type` from json and show it in `ListView`. As you can see that the json have `item_list`. 

Let say that I press the `Sort By` on `ListView`. After that Its open the other activity that show "Ascending" and "Descending" on `ListView`.

If it can do it without passing trought intent I prefer that option. Can you give an example for that case?

Comment: @Matthew And what is the problem?

Comment: Can you give me an example or a tutorial to parse it without passing it throught intent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57969/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-matthew).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have

```
String item_list = itemList.toString();
```

You need to parse `items_list` which is a `JSONArray`.

```
JSONArray itemList = new JSONArray(c.getString("item_list"));
// loop through the array itemList and get the items
for(int i=0;i<itemList.length();i++) 
{ 
String item = itemList.getString(i); // item at index i
}
```

Now you can add the strings to a list/array and then do what is required.

Comment: What If I have a dinamic data? Not just Ascend and Descend?

Comment: @Matthew you still be looping through the array from 0 to end of array and use the index to get the items required

Comment: there's an error on `String item = itemsList.getString(i); // item at index i` that the itemList variable cannot be resolved.

Comment: @Matthew where do you have that piece of code?. `itemList` is `JSONArray itemList = new JSONArray(c.getString("item_list"));`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its done. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look on this tutorial.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Maybe this would help you.

```
ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i< count; i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        stringArray.add(jsonObject.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```